# react to laravel csrf token mismatch error not working even after trying lot

Tags: php, laravel, csrf-token

i have tried following things . but still csrf issue persists when sedning post request from react to laravel

i have used barryvh middleware cors to fixed cors issue

in cors.php

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
   'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
   'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type', 'X-Requested-With','token','user_token','_token','X-CSRF-TOKEN'],
   'allowedMethods' => ['*'], // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
   'exposedHeaders' => [],
   'maxAge' => 0,
```

1. meta tags in page

   ```
      return (
         <div className="Login" style={{fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',height:'36em'}}>
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"></input>
           <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
           {/* { csrf_token() } */}
           {/* { @csrf } */}
           {/* { csrf_field() }*/}
   ```
2. meta tag in root (index.html)
3. tried following commented code  in post

   ```
     return fetch("www.campaignserver.com:3001/test", 
           {
               method: 'post',
               credentials: "same-origin",
               headers: {
                       'Accept': 'application/json',
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                       //"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                       "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                       'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector("[name~=csrf-token] 
              [content]").content
                   },
   ```
4. laravel side -- route.api.php

   ```
      // Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/test', function (Request $request) {
      //     return response()->json(['message' =>'corstest'], 200);
      // });
      // Route::post('test', 'HomeController@test');
     // Route::get('test', 'HomeController@test');
   ```

how can i identity the root cause .?please suggest

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using laravel as an api, using CSRF token doesn't make sense.

By default, when you use the route file `routes/api.php` there is no CSRF token verification in place. You can verify that in `app/Http/Kernel.php`:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class, //<-- HERE IS THE CSRF VERIFICATION
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [ //<--- AS you can see there is no VerifyCsrfToken middleware in API
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        'throttle:300,1', 
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

For The route you're calling, routes declared in `routes/api.php` have a prefix by default, you can check that in `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` @ `mapApiRoutes`:

```php
/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api') //<-- here is the prefix
         ->middleware('api') //<-- this is the kernel middleware used for this route group
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php')); //<-- and here is the related file
}
```

Comment: web array contains csrf already , in api array i added what you said , stll same issue . i also tried to remmove token param in header array , still issue is sam ,with or without

Comment: @NeerajVerma the POST route you're using is in `api.php` route file ?

Comment: is your base url in `Const.URL.SERVER_BASE_URL + "/test"` equal to `domain.com/api` ? or just the domain ?

Comment: just domain .. full url is www.campaignserver.com:3001

Comment: by default all routes declared in `routes/api.php` have a prefix "api", so you should call for `domain.com/api/test`

Comment: do i also need to declare custom route in route.api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202550/discussion-between-neeraj-verma-and-n69s).

Comment: i tried return fetch("http://api.campaignserver.com:3001/test", 
   {, ... still same issue

Answer (score 3):

in my case I was using sanctum and this line in the app/kernel.php was causing the issue

> EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class

I just removed it and it is working now

api clause should look like this:

```
'api' => [
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you so much and I think this answer should be accepted.