# Attempt to send an axios post request over a react app to laravel api returns 419 status

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, laravel-9, laravel-api

I'm trying to send an email with a contact form on my React.js app that send a post request to the laravel api server, but upon trying to actually send the request, I get the error 419 (CSRF token missing) but since it's an api I can't actually get the cookie as i could in laravel view folder. Any ideas?

```js
export const csrf = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/contact"
 const data = {
                name: name,
                subject: subject,
                email: email,
                message: message,
            }
axios.post(contactUrl, data).then((response) => console.log(response));
```

This is the react app part

```
    Route::post('/contact', [ContactController::class, 'send'])
        ->name('send-mail');
```

And this is my route defined in Api.php

Comment: Add csrf token to your Axios interceptor header. Check: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-use-csrf-token-with-axios-post-method?page=1&replyId=372941

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Sorry but my react app is on another domain so I cannot call the csrf cookie from the metatags

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910214/react-to-laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-error-not-working-even-after-trying-lot